# I read code from my php file in java and I want to split the line of code by event

Tags: java, php

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class AppDev {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

URL website = new URL("MyWebsite.php");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
new InputStreamReader(website.openStream()));

    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(inputLine);
        sb.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();
  }
}
```

I have this code which reads from a php file and displays this output:

```
Event Number: 1
Date: 2018-05-16
Time: 12:00:00
Event: meeting with friend
Event Number: 5
Date: 2018-05-03
Time: 01:34:37
Event: what the hell
Event Number: 6
Date: 2018-05-03
Time: 01:35:05
Event: Rage at MySQL
Event Number: 16
Date: 2018-06-20
Time: 08:00:00
Event: hfdhfdfgfg
```

I would like to split each event and its information by its own in an array for example and then output each array in a jtextfield for example the first entry would be

```
Event Number: 1
Date: 2018-05-03
Time: 01:34:37
Event: meeting with friend
```

and so on

Comment: Do you have control on the PHP script? If yes, you should change it so that the response uses a data encoding format, like JSON for example, to help you parse the results without having to implement your own system. By the way, what did you try/searched to solve your problem? (should add it to your question)

Answer (score 0):

This trick may help you

**Input**

```
$string = 'Event Number: 1Date: 2018-05-16Time: 12:00:00Event: meeting with friendEvent Number: 5Date: 2018-05-03Time: 01:34:37Event: what the hellEvent Number: 6Date: 2018-05-03Time: 01:35:05Event: Rage at MySQLEvent Number: 16Date: 2018-06-20Time: 08:00:00Event: hfdhfdfgfg';
```

**Solution**

Add a special element or word that not occur in the string before **Event Number** and removes the first occurrence of that by [ltrim](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_ltrim.asp). The [str_replace](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_str_replace.asp) will replace `Event Number` to `|Event Number`.

I used `|` here.

Code is as follows:

```
$string = ltrim(str_replace('Event Number','|Event Number',$string),'|');
$array = explode('|',$string);//convert the string into array.
echo "<pre>";print_r($array);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Event Number: 1Date: 2018-05-16Time: 12:00:00Event: meeting with friend
    [1] => Event Number: 5Date: 2018-05-03Time: 01:34:37Event: what the hell
    [2] => Event Number: 6Date: 2018-05-03Time: 01:35:05Event: Rage at MySQL
    [3] => Event Number: 16Date: 2018-06-20Time: 08:00:00Event: hfdhfdfgfg
)
```